# Wordpress How to add Admin Custom Column Sorting by display value

Tags: php, wordpress, jquery-ui-sortable, backend, custom-post-type

In Wordpress, is there a way to make a custom column sortable by the display value instead of the meta_value? What I mean is that my meta value is a number, but I've manipulated that number with an existing hook for it to be a string. I'd like to sort by that string instead of the number. This is my existing, working code that will sort it just fine - it just won't be in alphabetical order:

```
add_action('manage_resource_posts_custom_column', 'my_manage_resource_columns', 10, 2);
function my_manage_resource_columns($column_name, $id) {
    switch ($column_name) {
    case 'type':
        $id = get_the_ID();
        $par = get_field('resource_type',$id);
        $type = get_field('singular_name',$par);
        echo $type;
            break;
    default:
        break;
    }
} 

add_filter( "manage_edit-resource_sortable_columns", "my_last_modified_column_register_sortable" );
function my_last_modified_column_register_sortable( $columns ) {
    $columns["type"] = "type";
    return $columns;
}

add_filter( "request", "sort_column_by_modified" ); 
function sort_column_by_modified( $vars ){
    if ( isset( $vars["orderby"] ) && "type" == $vars["orderby"] && $_GET['post_type']=='resource') {
        $vars = array_merge( $vars, array(
            'meta_key' => 'resource_type',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
        ) );
    }
    return $vars;
}
```

So you can see where I add the actual text for the column name based on the numeric value in the database. It displays fine. I just need it to be sortable by that text and not the value it represents. Does anyone know if this is possible / how to do it?

Here is a screen shot of the column as it is now. You can see that they are indeed grouped up by type, but its by numerical order of the ID

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort a column on more than one meta value, you will use the meta_query argument for your sort algorithm. To give an example as to when you would want to sort on more than one parameter. Lets say you you have a list of TV shows listed by Season and Episode. To sort by Episode alone would put all the Episodes 1 together, etc., but what really want, when sort by Episode to also to sort by Season-Episode, as this is more readable and understanding to the admin user.

To accomplish this, in the sort_column_by_modified function, replace

```
$vars = array_merge( $vars, array(
        'meta_key' => 'resource_type',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
    ) );
```

with

```
$vars = array_merge( $vars, array(
        'meta_query' => array(
              array(
                  'meta_key' => 'season',  // the column name
                  'order_by_num' => 'meta_value_num'
              ),
              array(
                  'meta_key' => 'episode', // the column name
                  'order_by_num' => 'meta_value_num'
              ),
         )
    ) );
```

For other types of sorts, adjust your meta_query appropriately.